# Show that $2+ \sqrt{-5}$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $2+ \sqrt{-5}$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5}$.

Here is my approach:
If $2+ \sqrt{-5}$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5}$, then for all $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5}$ we would have:
$2+ \sqrt{-5} \mid rs \Rightarrow 2+ \sqrt{-5} \mid r$ or $2+ \sqrt{-5} \mid s$.

We can consider the function $N :\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, such that
$N(a+b\sqrt{-5})=(a+b\sqrt{-5})(a-b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2$.

The next thing is to recognize, that if $a\mid b$ in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5}$, then $N(a) \mid N(b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.
This means that, if $2+ \sqrt{-5} \mid r \Rightarrow N(2+ \sqrt{-5}) \mid N(r)$.

Next, we notice that, $N(2+ \sqrt{-5})=9$.

Now, $9 \mid 3 \cdot 6$ but $9 \nmid 3$ and $9 \nmid 6$.
Thus, $2+ \sqrt{-5}$ can't be prime in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5}$.

Question:
Is my approach correct?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist That argument is used to show $2+\sqrt{-5}$ is *irreducible*, not to show that it is not prime.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You know that if $a$ divides $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, then $N(a)$ divides $N(b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

However:

1. You don't have an $N(a)$ and an $N(b)$. You have $N(a)$, $N(2+\sqrt{-5})$, and integers $3$ and $6$, and note that $N(a)$ divides $18$ but does not divide $3$ nor $6$. So? You have not even shown an element $b\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ with $N(b)=18$, or $6$, or $3$.
2. And even if you did, you have the wrong implication. It is not necessarily true that if $N(a)$ divides $N(b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $a$ divides $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. For example, $N(3)=9$ divides $N(2+\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, but $3$ does not divide $2+\sqrt{-5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, since any  multiple of $3$ is of the form $3a+3b\sqrt{-5}$, and $2+\sqrt{-5}$ does not have that form.

So you are *trying* to affirm the consequent (which is already a fallacy), and you did not even affirm the consequent, but something else.

You are right that what you need to do is find two elements $rs$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $2+\sqrt{-5}$ divides $rs$, but divides neither $r$ nor $s$. And the norm might help there, perhaps to show that $2+\sqrt{-5}$ does not divide either $r$ or $s$ (because if $N(2+\sqrt{-5})$ does **not** divide $N(r)$, then $2+\sqrt{-5}$ does not divide $r$); but you can't go from "norm of $a$ divides $m$" to "$a$ divides a product but not either of the factors."

Comment: @Thank you for your feedback. I did think a little bit about it, but I can't figure aout a way to find such elements $rs$ in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5}$, s.t. $2+\sqrt{-5} \mid rs$ but $2+ \sqrt{-5} \nmid r$. Could you give me a hint on how to find those elements?

Comment: @NTc5 $(2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5}) = 4+5 = 9$.

Comment: Does this work: Since $(2+\sqrt{-5})(2-\sqrt{-5})=9$, we know that
$2+\sqrt{-5} \mid 9$.
Now I have to show that $2+\sqrt{-5} \nmid 3$.
Lets assume that $2+\sqrt{-5} \mid 3$, then there exists $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5}$ such that 

$(2+\sqrt{-5})(a+b\sqrt{-5})=3$

The left side is equal to $(2a-5b) +(a+2b)\sqrt{-5}$. Thus we get the equations $2a-5b=3$ and $a+2b=0$.
Solving those we get $a=\frac{2}{3}$ and $b=-\frac{1}{3}$. Because $a,b \notin \mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-5}$, we can conclude that $2+\sqrt{-5} \nmid 3$.

Comment: @NTc5 You can do that; or you can note that $N(3) =9$, so if $(2+\sqrt{-5})$ divides $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, then there exists $r$ with $N(r)=1$ such that $(2+\sqrt{-5})r=3$. But the only elements with $N(r)=1$ are $\pm 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One should notice that
$\begin{array}
.(1-\sqrt{-5})^2
&=1-2\sqrt{-5}+(-5)\\
&=-2(2+\sqrt{-5})\\
\end{array}$
so that $2+\sqrt{-5}\,\mid (1-\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5}).$

But, $2+\sqrt{-5}\nmid 1-\sqrt{-5}$, because $N(2+\sqrt{-5})=9$,  $N(1-\sqrt{-5})=6$ and $9\nmid 6$.

So $2+\sqrt{-5}$ is not prime in $\Bbb Z[-5]$.